# Unusual behavior of Ruby script while working with sockets

Tags: ruby, sockets, serversocket, behavior

The thing is that I am very beginner in Ruby programming and I have some troubles with understanding  Ruby's behavior.

Here is the code:

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.new 2000
loop do
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|

    puts 'Client connected: ' + client.gets

    line = "-1"

    while (line != "/close ")
      line = client.gets();
      puts line
    end

    puts 'client closed'
    client.close
  end
end
```

As you see, it's a simple socket server waiting for some input information. 
The problem is that when it gets "/close ", it exits the while loop, but never goes to 
`puts 'client closed'` and `client.close`. So why is it so, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that if you change `puts line` to `puts line.inspect` you will see the problem.

---

Found it? `gets` reads by lines, which includes the line-terminating `\n`, so no line you get will ever equal `"/close "`. Changing the comparison to use `line.strip` will work, for example.

Comment: thank you very mush, after `line.strip` and removing " " from `"/close "` all worked as expected!